# How to change Ember.js location from where it serves the static assets

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am a beginner at Ember.js, so sorry if this is an easy question, but I couldn't locate the answer.

Basically, after running `ember build`, Ember's `index.html` will have these links for the built `.js` files:

```
<script src="assets/vendor-4d126b4b021a3ad999a0115386f5edf4.js" integrity=""></script>
<script src="assets/bsrs-ember-1906440e1018cb4d5bdbe009ff42b763.js" integrity=""></script>
```

I'd like to change these links in `index.html` to:

```
<script src="/static/assets/vendor-4d126b4b021a3ad999a0115386f5edf4.js" integrity=""></script>
<script src="/static/assets/bsrs-ember-1906440e1018cb4d5bdbe009ff42b763.js" integrity=""></script>
```

Is this possible?  If so, how do you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to alter the ember-cli-build file (previously called the Brocfile) to ensure a special prefix gets added to the front of your assets (note: only done for production builds)

```
var app = new EmberApp({
    fingerprint: {
      prepend: '/static/'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing path of `vendor.js` you can pass `app.outputPaths.vendor.js` property to `EmberApp` in `ember-cli-build.js`:

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  outputPaths: {
    vendor: {
      js: '/static/assets/vendor.js'
    }
  }
});
```